# How can i send the request and receive the response (JSON ) via JAVA (android)?

Tags: java, android, json, get

How can I send in java(android) the http request and parse response in JSON format. I know that this is simple but i'm newbie in Java (android).

Comment: check this out http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_network_connection.htm

Comment: hmm i don't know but internet is working but i can connect even with google.com

Comment: ok, solved http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/06/app-force-close-honeycomb-ics.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you would want to send a simple http get request to the provided url.
To send a simple GET request:

1. Create an object of HttpClient

`HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();`

2. Create an object of HttpGet

`HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://www.example.com");`

3. make request to the server side

`HttpResponse response;`

```
try {
response = client.execute(request);

    Log.d("Response of GET request", response.toString());
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Then depending on the format of your response, you want to parse it.
Also don't forget to include necessary permission on your manifest.xml file such as permission to use internet.

Comment: not working, application was stopped at line response = client.execute(request);

Answer (score 0):

you can also check out volley:

http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html